# this Excel VBA code doesn't update automatically when its run

Tags: excel, vba

```
Option Explicit
Sub Customer_Load()
Dim CustRow As Long, LastInvRow As Long, LastWORow As Long, CustCol As Long
With Sheet1
    If .Range("B10").Value = Empty Then
    MsgBox "Please Select Customer"
       Exit Sub
    End If
        CustRow = .Range("B10").Value
        .Range("E3,E5,E7,E9,E11,H3,H5,H7,H9,H11,D13:H15").ClearContents
        For CustCol = 2 To 11
            .Range(Sheet2.Cells(1, CustCol).Value).Value = Sheet2.Cells(CustRow, CustCol).Value
        Next CustCol
    
End With

End Sub
```

I wanted to fetch the data from sheet2 and bring them in cells in sheet1

Comment: This indirect cell addressing looks a little strange to me. What is the content of the first row of sheet2?

Comment: What is happening? Is there an error (which one: error number and description)? What are you trying to do? Copy `B:K` from `Sheet2` in `CustRow` to `B:K` in `Sheet1` first row? Maybe add the screenshots of both worksheets and one of the result after the copying.

Comment: I don't think it will ever update because right after you check if B10 is "empty" your code exits the sub; thus it will not accomplish the rest of the code.

Comment: @GMalc But if `B10` is not empty it will continue.